# React complains "error:25078067:DSO support routines:win32_load:could not load the shared library," no OpenSSL binaries have this library. How to fix?

Tags: openssl, react.js

I installed a Windows-compatible OpenSSL binary from Shining Light Productions and then used that binary in the Win64 OpenSSL Command Prompt to generate a certificate and key like so:

```
openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.cert
```

This command ran successfully, but I then tried to use the below command to get React's development server to load with the certificate and key:

```
set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=server.key&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=server.cert&&react-scripts start
```

and got this error:

> error:25078067:DSO support routines:win32_load:could not load the
> shared library

A search of my computer files indicates that this file is not on my computer.

I downloaded another binary and this also does not have the file.

How do I fix this?

Comment: are you sure those `&&`'s shouldn't have spaces around them? and I don't think the message is telling you that it can't find win32_load (which is an api operation, not a file) but that it failed to load a shared library, that is unspecified. Win32_Load loads shared libraries. in this case it couldn't. the message does not say what library or why it failed. if you haven't already, you may want to make sure that the dev server is running as admin. if it isn't then the userspace server may be your issue.

Comment: According to my research is an indication the OpenSSL binary is the problem. If you conclude that isn't the case the syntax is likely incorrect.  Is there a reason you are not using `.env.development` for your React environment? Make sure your version of React supports HTTPS developement.